# Facebook App request Dialog keep loading on mobile after FB.login() called

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have code like this:

```
FB.login( function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            //code about sending access Token to server

            FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'myApp' }, function(response){});
        }
});
```

**Expected result**: after user accepts the permissions, an app request dialog shows up.

**What happened**: It works perfectly fine on desktop. However on mobile, the dialog just keeps on loading and doesn't show anything.

I find one interesting fact is, if I put FB.ui() before FB.login(), the dialog shows up normally on mobile. (However if I put after, doesn't work anymore)

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a very old bug that was fixed. Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: I have tested on several mobile phones and found out that it works on most phones (not not on mine). I haven't tested it recently but I hope this was fixed.